# Single Responsibility Principle Core Understanding

Tags: single-responsibility-principle

In brushing up on the SRP I read [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByOwmqah_nuGNHEtcU5OekdDMkk/view) document which I located via [Uncle Bob's page](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) on principles of OOD.  I find the following passage puzzling and somewhat at odds with the rest of the document:

*"If, on the other hand, the application is not changing in ways that cause the the two responsibilities to change at different times, then there is no need to separate them. Indeed, separating them would smell of Needless Complexity.  There is a corollary here. An axis of change is only an axis of change if the changes actually occur. It is not wise to apply the SRP, or any other principle for that matter, if there is no symptom."*

While I understand the answer to many software development questions is "it depends" principles like the SRP appear to be almost universally beneficial and to be implemented as a matter of course.  The SRP itself affords code a high adaptability to *future* changes in requirements.  Isn't the point to separate out responsibilities from the get-go to avoid struggling with highly coupled code and cascading changes later on?

I would really appreciate some clarification on this to make sure my understanding of this core principle is correct.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regardless of what principles are applied or not, you should aim for code which is easy, safe and quick to change. Many principles drive that out but, as Uncle Bob points out, it is often the case that if a principle is applied inappropriately, what should have been a simple piece of code becomes unnecessarily complex. I don't think this is unique to the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your comment, the crux of my question is the seeming conflict between not applying the principle if there is no symptom, versus applying it proactively to minimise the impact when symptoms appear in time (i.e. when requirements change).

Answer (score 0):

From my humble understanding, in the `Modem` example that is presented here, it might be possible that responsibilities of the modem (**Connection** and **Data Exchange**) will change as one.

You have two possibilities here :

- When the protocol changes, it is possible that only the **connection** part change, or only the **data exchange** part change. It this case you should have two interfaces, because a change of protocol in the data does not imply a change of protocol in the connection.
- When the protocol changes, it will always change the **connection** part and the **data exchange** part. In that case, you don't need two interfaces, because everytime you will have to rewrite the connection part, you are sure that the data exchange will change as well. In that case, you have two responsibilities put on the same change Axis (which is the protocol handled by the modem), so you can leave them inside a single interface.

Comment: This is interesting.  However if we are saying that ahead of time we are judging whether multiple responsibilities will change as one or separately, can we really know? We're predicting the unknown, is it not always better to separate out the responsibilities to cater for whatever is thrown at us? In your example, surely both possibilities are, well, possible? Therefore we should apply the SRP?

Comment: @Constantine I believe it might depend on external sources. If they state that these responsibilities will move together or not...

Answer (score 0):

The key to this statement is "not changing in ways that cause the two responsibilities to change at different times". Let's say for the sake of argument you have a **PaymentLogger** and a **Payment** class. Every time you create a new **PaymentType** (CreditCard, Cash, Paypal, etc) you need to update the **PaymentLogger** to log actions specific to those **Payments**. Instead of splitting out a **PaymentLogger** class you could have **Payment** class have a method called *Log* which does whatever is specific for itself.

In this case it could be that the act of recording actions should be build into the class itself since creating a new **Payment** requires also creating a new **PaymentLogger**. It's a responsibility that should have been part of **Payment** all along.